# Human wants are limited. What part of speech is "limited"?

Tags: grammar

Human wants are limited.

Is this sentence in passive form?

Is the 'limited' word an adjective?

Comment: [How to phrase a question in English: What part of speech **does** limited denote?]

Answer (score 1):

If you start with

> Human nature limits human wants.

you can passivize that as

> Human wants are limited by human nature.

That would be a passive expression with the transitive verb *limit*.

With your example

> Human wants are limited.

without naming an agent for *limited*, it is probably better analyzed as an adjective, with *are* as a copulative verb.
In fact dictionaries list *limited* as an adjective.

Comment: But if i ignore the rest part (by nature) then would 'limited' be  an adjective.

Comment: Yes, it's an adjective.

Comment: Thnks for your suggestion

Comment: Evidence that it's an adjective is that you can modify it with "very", "quite", "more", etc, "Human wants are very limited", "Human wants are more limited", which you couldn't do with the passive.